# android studio database app crashes without error

Tags: java, android, mysql

Hi my name is Simon and this is my first time using android studio or even java.
but I need to do this for my job application so I am learning along the way.

I am making an app that adds ships to my online database. 
when I try to add a ship to my database the app crashes. I still receive my `toast`. but I don't see the new ship in my database. I am running this on an emulator so I can connect with my internal IP.

so what else do I need to get this to add ships to my database ?

```
package com.example.simon.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by simon on 14-10-2017.
 */

public class BackgoundTasks extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
Context ctx;

BackgoundTasks (Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


String RegisterURL = "http://10.0.0.2.2/webapp/register.php";

String method = params[0];
   // if (method.equals("register")) {
        String Shipname = params[1];
        String manufacturer = params[2];
        String price = params[3];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(RegisterURL);
            HttpURLConnection httpConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpConnect.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConnect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpConnect.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferdWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
            // send info to server
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Sending data ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("Shipname", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Shipname, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("manufacturer", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(manufacturer, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("price", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(price, "UTF-8");
            bufferdWriter.write(data);
            bufferdWriter.flush();
            bufferdWriter.close();
            OS.close();

            InputStream IS = httpConnect.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return "Ship added";


    //}

}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
10-16 15:10:20.476 22877-22877/? E/Zygote: v2
10-16 15:10:20.476 22877-22877/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10300
10-16 15:10:20.476 22877-22877/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
10-16 15:10:20.478 22877-22877/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
10-16 15:10:20.499 22877-22877/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[1],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 SPD:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0006 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0005, [-1 -1 0 1 0 1]
10-16 15:10:20.502 22877-22877/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.simon.myapplication 
10-16 15:10:20.508 22877-22877/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-16 15:10:20.536 22877-22877/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
10-16 15:10:20.642 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.simon.myapplication-2/lib/arm64
10-16 15:10:20.720 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ContextRelationMgrBrdg: loadKlass() : caller=com.samsung.android.bridge.multiscreen.common.ContextRelationManagerBridge.<clinit>:28 android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication:840 
10-16 15:10:20.736 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-16 15:10:20.794 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-16 15:10:20.953 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=75
10-16 15:10:20.953 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@8e6c3d3[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@21ddb10[MainActivity] touchMode=true
10-16 15:10:21.090 22877-22931/com.example.simon.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-16 15:10:21.090 22877-22931/com.example.simon.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
10-16 15:10:21.096 22877-22931/com.example.simon.myapplication D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.simon.myapplication
10-16 15:10:21.098 22877-22931/com.example.simon.myapplication D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
10-16 15:10:21.243 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
10-16 15:10:21.249 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@8e6c3d3[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
10-16 15:10:21.249 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@8e6c3d3[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
10-16 15:10:21.252 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@bf8eeed nm : com.example.simon.myapplication ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@a182122
10-16 15:10:21.252 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
10-16 15:10:21.259 22877-22898/com.example.simon.myapplication D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=85
10-16 15:10:21.274 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@8aaa7b3 nm : com.example.simon.myapplication ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@7342170
10-16 15:10:22.844 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@8e6c3d3[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-16 15:10:22.846 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
10-16 15:10:22.849 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
10-16 15:10:22.849 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
10-16 15:10:23.050 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@8e6c3d3[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-16 15:10:23.072 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
10-16 15:10:23.075 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-16 15:10:23.076 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-16 15:10:23.093 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@8e6c3d3[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
10-16 15:10:23.442 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://myserveradres
10-16 15:10:23.462 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
10-16 15:10:23.462 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.simon.myapplication.BackgoundTasks.doInBackground(BackgoundTasks.java:82)
10-16 15:10:23.462 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.simon.myapplication.BackgoundTasks.doInBackground(BackgoundTasks.java:22)
10-16 15:10:23.462 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
10-16 15:10:23.462 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-16 15:10:23.462 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
10-16 15:10:23.462 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
10-16 15:10:23.462 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
10-16 15:10:23.462 22877-23154/com.example.simon.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
10-16 15:10:23.496 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=85
10-16 15:10:23.496 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
10-16 15:10:23.496 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
10-16 15:10:23.504 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=88
10-16 15:10:23.504 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@8477c46[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{2716e07 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} touchMode=true
10-16 15:10:23.511 22877-22931/com.example.simon.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x776d5f7c00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x778198ae60
10-16 15:10:23.581 22877-22931/com.example.simon.myapplication D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [156x132]-format:1
10-16 15:10:23.582 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@8477c46[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
10-16 15:10:23.868 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@8e6c3d3[MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
10-16 15:10:23.886 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=75
10-16 15:10:27.017 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@8477c46[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
10-16 15:10:27.033 22877-22877/com.example.simon.myapplication D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=88
```

Comment: Have you tried to use Logcat? There could be many reasons why your app is crashing. We can only help you if you provide a so called 'stacktrace', you can open in Android Studio by clicking the Android Monitor tab.

Comment: thanks i have added the logcat underneeth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your Logcat, we can see the following line:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
>   10.0.0.2.2/webapp/register.php

Which means, you should try adding `http://` in front of the address you are refering to. Due the Exception, the app will jump straight to the code:

```
 catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Which means that all code above it is not being executed, and that might be the cause of the crash.

Comment: it is still there. i have updated the logcat.
getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa3265280
is in red.

Comment: Now it says that it cannot find the host, so either the link is wrong or it does not exists.

Comment: some people told me it could heve been an android 6.0 issue. after testing it with my partners s7 (wich runs android 7) i can confirm that this is not the case. i have also uploaded the catlog form her phone. it just crashes.

Comment: th correct ip was 10.0.0.2.2:80/webapp/Register.php